# Sharing emails / open in browser from Inbox/Gmail apps?

Tags: gmail, share-menu, intents, inbox-by-gmail

Is it possible to share emails from the GMail or Inbox apps?  The content of the intent isn't incredibly important.  It could be the full content of the email or be limited to the subject line or even just be a HTTP link to that email on gmail.com.

**Alternatively:**

Is it possible to open an email in the browser from GMail / Inbox?  There are numerous possibilities in that case.

Comment: Resend the mail?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'resend'

Comment: You know...you can resend emails since forever.

Comment: "Forwarding" or re-composing emails creates a new email (and does not create an implicit intent which is what this question is asking for).

Comment: You want to open it in the browser, from the gmail or inbox app? Sorry I didn't understand. Just tried it in gmail and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Yes; like some form of 'share' button you commonly find in Android apps to share a URL or picture.  What exactly it shares of the stored email isn't important; only that some reference of this email (like it's sender + subject line as plain text) is available to another application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's no feature as such. But there are ways you can "share".

Text: Click and hold to select text.

Images and similar attachments: Click to preview/Download.

Then you can use the *Share* menu to send it to other apps or *Copy to Clipboard*.

Then there's the *Screenshot* option. Depending on your phone model, the key combination to take a shot may vary.

--

Some emails contain a text logically written as *Open in browser*. That's rare, though.